# Calculating and comparing weighted means with changing number of daily values

Tags: time-series, structural-equation-modeling, weighted-mean

I have daily data where the number of values changes with each day. I would like to calculate the weighted mean of this data, where days with more values are weighted higher than days with less.

**Conceptualized data**:

```
  day1     day2       day3      day4
[3,1,2] [4,1,4,5] [4,5,1,7,8] [3,4,5]
```

What is the correct way of weighting these values, and how might I compare the means of different data-sets (like with the SEM) with a similar structure, but different number of values per day?

Comment: Do you actually have the values 3,1,2, and 4,1,4,5 etc available?

Comment: Those are just dummy values that I used for my example.

Comment: Ahem. If you observe $n_i$ values on day $i$, do you have the $n_i$ individual values available to you?

Comment: I see. Yes, I do.

Comment: Then just take a straight average of them all. The average of a day with 3 values will get 3/5 the "weight" of the average of a day with 5 values.

Comment: geez... i have been confusing myself with other details in my system, and I just wasn't processing this for some reason. That makes things easy :) Thanks.

Comment: Would you like something like that posted as an answer?

Comment: Finished. Sorry it took me a few days, I was having trouble finding a good way to put it that would be more generally useful, but I think I got there in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two typical cases when you get multiple points per group (per day in your case) and want to weight for the number of values per group:

- the individual points are not available, only their mean and the number of values. Then you weight by the number of values (in a weighted average or a weighted regression, for example).
- the individual points are available. Then you simply include all the individual points - the repeated values themselves provide the 'weight' - a group with two observations will get two observations of weight, while a group with five observations will get all five providing weight.

You're in the second case, so there's nothing to do - just use all your data. If you are (for example) computing an overall mean, then a straight average of all the data gives more weight to the days with more data.